# File upload stops when it started

Tags: javascript, django, nginx, file-upload, large-files

I developed a video upload page on a web site. Whe I try to upload a video file smaller than ~100mb everything works perfect but if I try to upload a larger file, the upload process stops at the beginning and continues after a couples minutes.

I'm using Hetzner (Ubuntu 18) for my production server and DigitalOcean(Ubuntu 20) for staging. In the staging file uploading process doesn't care the file size. it's works like a charm, but in the production server the upload stops at the begining.

Both servers has the same configuration (i handle the deployment and server configs with an Ansible script). They works on the same code, they have same nginx, supervisor and gunicorn configs but in the production server the upload stops.

I've tried a lot of different structures in javascript, but nothing changed. Staging works, production fails. The only difference between two server is Ubuntu version but I don't think OS version would be an issue for a simple file upload.

Here's my console.log output for the upload progress.
You can see there are a lot of time between first and second output.

[image: console log output]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a difference in the available space in the `/tmp` directory on each server? This is where large uploaded files will be written to by Django as a default

Comment: i've checked but the prod's disk %99 empty (~2TB), staging is %53 loaded (DO's cheapest)

Comment: The issue may be with Hetzner? Worth contacting their support